# How do I choose the subset of IKVM dlls that are relevant to my project?

Tags: c#, mono, ikvm

So I created an assembly referenced library of SVNKit (Java) using IKVM. In my project, I referenced all of the IKVM DLLS to use the SVNKit, however, I'm pretty sure not all of them are used. And there are alot of DLLs included.

Is there a way other than trial and error to find the subset of IKVM DLLs that are relevant?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The required assemblies are:

- IKVM.Runtime.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.Core.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.Util.dll

Other assemblies are only needed if you use those parts of the class library.

SVNKit probably needs some of the XML assemblies:

- IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.API.dll
- IKVM.OpenJDK.XML.Parse.dll

Michael Kay's article [Analyzing dependencies in a class library: a use case for XSLT streaming](http://dev.saxonica.com/blog/mike/2009/09/#000166) describes a method for determining which IKVM assemblies a project needs.